# How to get the environment variable WEBSITE_PRIVATE_PORTS set in Azure App Service?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, orleans

I have used the [following sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Orleans-Cluster-on-Azure-App-Service) to set up an ASP.Net Core application running in Azure App Service along with Orleans.

I have my App Service (S1:2) deployed and connected to a `VNet`.

However to be able to work, the ASP.Net service must have access to an environment variable called [WEBSITE_PRIVATE_PORTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#networking). It is supposed to contain private ports that can be used by an app to communicate with other services.

As shown in the sample, these ports are [used](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Orleans-Cluster-on-Azure-App-Service/blob/edd8b9f491730cc628896ff766cc9b4b216cc0b8/Silo/Program.cs#L19) to set up Orleans.

To get access to this environment variable, the documentation states that it only requires a VNet integration. This is what I did but I still do not see the environment variable in my App Service.

**Question**

What do I need to do get access to the environment variable `WEBSITE_PRIVATE_PORTS` in my Azure App Service?

Comment: Not sure to really understand, do you want to use this environment variable in your ASP .NET Core application ?

Comment: @yguerin I have tried to put a bit more information. I want to use this environment variable in my application but it is not available and I do not know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there is a configuration setting in the [siteConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites?tabs=bicep#siteconfig) section of the App Service.

For instance in bicep, the setting `vnetPrivatePortsCount` assigns the defined number of private ports to be used by the app.

It can also assign using an Azure CLI command:

`az command: az webapp config set -g {ressource_group_name} -n {app_service_name} --generic-configurations '{"vnetPrivatePortsCount": 2}'`

Once this setting is configured, these ports can now be visible in the Kudo console and used by the application:

[image: Kudo console]